# TYPO3 8.4.0 : failed to open stream: ResourceCompressor.php

Tags: php, installation, typo3, typo3-8.x

I've installed TYPO3 8.4.0. Everything is running well except the page,view,list,... panels because the javascript files that open them are not being loaded.

Bellow is a screenshot of the log. I've installed TYPO3 with Xampp exactly following the INSTALL.md file creating the symlinks.

[image: 1]

Bellow is again a copy of one of the errors. It looks like the filepath contains

```
Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: file_get_contents(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mytypoproject/typo3//mytypoproject/typo3/sysext/backend/Resources/Public/JavaScript/extjs/components/pagetree/javascript/app.js)
```

Here is the lines in `typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Resource/ResourceCompressor.php` where the error appears:

```
$filenameAbsolute = GeneralUtility::resolveBackPath($this->rootPath . $filename);
$filename = PathUtility::stripPathSitePrefix($filenameAbsolute);
$contents = file_get_contents($filenameAbsolute);
```

It looks like `rootPATH` and  `$filename` overlap `/mytypoproject/typo3/` and so are the files not found.

You know how I could solve this ? Is it an error from the installation ?
Thank you !

Comment: Looks like a bug somehow. Do you mind adding this to the bugtracker or asking in Slack?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your apache conf. In the Directory settings. Check if the setting `DocumentRoot` ended with an `/` and remove them. Restart than the apache server.

Comment: `<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>` but I think this is more than just a slash because /mytypoproject/typo3/ is overlapped